# Installation of xlwings using pip and from source gives an error in ubuntu vm

Tags: python, pip, python-module, xlwings

NameError: name 'data_files' is not defined

On further analysis I found that in setup.py the variable NameError: 'data_files' is defined under two if conditions

```
# Dependencies
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    install_requires = []  # pywin32 can't be installed (yet) with pip
    # This places dlls next to python.exe for standard setup and in the parent folder for virtualenv
    data_files = [('', ['xlwings32.dll', 'xlwings64.dll'])]
if sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
    install_requires = ['psutil >= 2.0.0', 'appscript >= 1.0.1']
    data_files =[]
```

Shouldn't this be handled for other environments also?

Comment: Yes, it  probably should. There's already a ticket on github for this issue: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/155

Comment: At this point in time, only Windows and Mac are supported.